# Set ringtone with webapp (sencha, ajax)

Tags: java, android, iphone, ajax, extjs

Is it possible to set a ringtone with a webapp (like with sencha for example) and not with a native app?

Comment: This is not possible as a webapp will never get the permissions it needs to edit system settings.

Comment: And what if you make a native app, that will call the webapp and give the permission? Or am I thinking way out of the box :) ?

Comment: If this is possible (and i doubt it) you will still need to do it from the native app, not from the web app.

Comment: You're thinking outside of the box you set yourself for your question. You asked whether you can set a ringtone from "webapp and not with a native app". The answer is then, "No."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are suggesting it yourself already (altough it depends on what you think a webapplication is). There are many frameworks that let you create an app with javascript (try appcelerator titanium for example) or html. You then can have access to native functions of the phone by using javascript.

I am not sure if appcelerator titanium lets you change the ringtone or let the phone ring...

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Nope, it is not possible.

Comment: Repeating a comment is not an answer.

Comment: It should be comment, not an answer

Comment: I was answering when there were no comments.. Thanks for the downvotes I was only trying to help.